# Promise no JS como Abortar/Cancelar uma em andamento

Tags: javascript, promises

Eu tenho uma função async salva dentro de um const, gostaria de finalizar ela após um tempo

exemplo:

```
const p = async () => {
   await Model.create();

  return;
}

const promise = p();

console.log(promise); // Promise { <pending> }


setTimeout(() => {
  // Finalizar o promise agora
}, 100)
```

Alguem sabe como faço isso, gostaria de tentar fazer isso sem mudar a função "p"

Comment: Você diz cancelar, porque o método create ainda não retornou?

Answer (score 1):

Não há como cancelar explicitamente uma `Promise` nativa. Se quiser uma alternativa existe o [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html), que fornece esse recurso. Esse post pode ajudar: https://blog.bloomca.me/2017/12/04/how-to-cancel-your-promise.html

Se quiser forçar um `reject`, terá que fazer isso dentro de `Model.create()`

Answer (score 1):

Conforme já citado em outras respostas, realmente não existe a possibilidade de se cancelar promessas em JavaScript. Afinal, como o próprio nome diz, é uma *promessa*, portanto, *sempre* há de haver uma resolução — seja resolvida ou rejeitada.

Você tem algumas opções. Uma delas é recorrer a bibliotecas terceiras, como o Bluebird, que oferece esse recurso, embora venha desligado por padrão. Saiba mais na [documentação](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/cancellation.html).

Uma outra opção é simplesmente não fazer nada na resolução da promessa. Algo assim:

```js
function getPromise(value) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(value), 1000);
  });
}

let cancel = true;

// Exemplo que será cancelado:
getPromise('Exemplo 1').then((resolvedValue) => {
  if (cancel) {
    return; // Não faça nada se tiver sido "cancelada":
  }
  
  console.log('Valor resolvido:', resolvedValue);
});

// Exemplo que NÃO será cancelado:
getPromise('Exemplo 2').then((resolvedValue) => {
  console.log('Valor resolvido:', resolvedValue);
});
```

Uma outra opção é usar o método [`Promise.race`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race), que resolve o valor da primeira promessa fornecida a ser resolvida. Sendo assim, você pode implementar um tipo de "timeout". Se uma dada promessa demorar demais para ser resolvida, uma segunda será resolvida.

```js
function getPromise(value, timeout) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(value), timeout);
  });
}

// Neste exemplo, o timeout será resolvido.
const exampleOnePromise = getPromise('Exemplo 1', 1500);
Promise.race([
  exampleOnePromise,
  getPromise('TIMEOUT do exemplo 1', 1000) // <-- Timeout
])
  .then((resolved) => console.log(resolved));
  
// Neste exemplo, o timeout não será resolvido,
// já que a promessa que queremos foi resolvida antes.
const exampleTwoPromise = getPromise('Exemplo 2', 1001);
Promise.race([
  exampleTwoPromise,
  getPromise('TIMEOUT do exemplo 2', 1501) // <-- Timeout
])
  .then((resolved) => console.log(resolved));
```

Como você pode ver, no primeiro exemplo do trecho acima, o "*timeout*" foi resolvido, já que a promessa que passamos demorou demais. No segundo, por outro lado, a promessa de exemplo foi resolvida antes.

Não há nada de muito especial aí. O *timeout* e a "promessa que testamos" são `Promise`s, só estamos simulando um comportamento de *timeout*.